# Netbeans 8 - Setup PHP syntax checking

Tags: php, netbeans

I've just installed Netbeans 8 want to set up php syntax checking. How do I do that?

I don't care about debugging a running file - just syntax.

Comment: You could have just downloaded the version that comes bundled with the PHP plugins. Syntax highlighting is enabled per default.

Comment: Ah ok, I was just thinking about getting the latest java jdk and netbeans at the time, should have checked the bundles. I'd rather not download netbeans again though - How to I get php seperately and enable it?

Comment: You've downloaded it like an hour ago. Didn't you stumble over the help meanwhile, or Tools>Plugins perhaps?

Comment: Plugins was what I wanted. Had to set the proxy server IP address and Port for it to work but now I have the updater tool. I did all this once before ages ago for an earlier netbeans but it's been so long I remembered incorrectly what I had to do to get php >_<

@mario could you post that comment as an answer? I'll mark it as such when you do.